# How to automatically skip over errors in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to create new variables from some output from a number of two-piece segmented regression models that I'm running. The code for my new variable is:

```
initial1=c(fmod$psi[1],fmod2$psi[1], fmod3$psi[1], fmod4$psi[1], fmod5$psi[1], fmod6$psi[1], fmod7$psi[1], fmod8$psi[1], fmod9$psi[1], fmod10$psi[1], fmod11$psi[1],fmod12$psi[1], fmod13$psi[1], fmod14$psi[1], fmod15$psi[1], fmod16$psi[1], fmod17$psi[1], fmod18$psi[1], fmod19$psi[1], fmod20$psi[1], fmod21$psi[1],fmod22$psi[1], fmod23$psi[1], fmod24$psi[1], fmod25$psi[1], fmod26$psi[1], fmod27$psi[1], fmod28$psi[1], fmod29$psi[1], fmod30$psi[1], fmod31$psi[1],fmod32$psi[1], fmod33$psi[1], fmod34$psi[1], fmod35$psi[1], fmod36$psi[1], fmod37$psi[1], fmod38$psi[1], fmod39$psi[1], fmod40$psi[1], fmod41$psi[1],fmod42$psi[1], fmod43$psi[1], fmod44$psi[1], fmod45$psi[1], fmod46$psi[1], fmod47$psi[1], fmod48$psi[1], fmod49$psi[1], fmod50$psi[1], fmod51$psi[1],fmod52$psi[1], fmod53$psi[1], fmod54$psi[1], fmod55$psi[1], fmod56$psi[1], fmod57$psi[1], fmod58$psi[1], fmod59$psi[1], fmod60$psi[1], fmod61$psi[1], fmod62$psi[1], fmod63$psi[1], fmod64$psi[1])
```

where fmod, fmod2, fmod3, etc. are my regression models. Some of the regression models have errors and do not produce output (because the initial breakpoint estimates are too close to each other). Because of that, when I try to make my 'initial1' variable, I get error messages such as:

```
Error: object 'fmod12' not found
```

and the 'initial' variable is not created. I would like these models that don't have output associated with them to be automatically skipped over, or to be replaced with 'NA'. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to recursively concatenate the models except those that had an error?

Comment: @MichaelDavidson Yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

You're creating many different models and giving them numbered names. Why not put them in a list instead?

At model creation time:

```
for (i in 1:lots) fmod[[i]] <- my_segmented_reg(...)
```

where `my_segmented_reg` presumably returns either a model, or `NULL` or `NA`.

Then you have a list `fmod` which you can start using straight away.